# After Update mutating table

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

can someone tell me how to avoid this mutating table error (ORA-04091)
I have to use a After Update Trigger for this homework.

```
AFTER UPDATE OF QTY,ACTUALPRICE  ON ITEM
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    UPDATE ITEM
    SET ITEMTOT = :new.QTY * :new.ACTUALPRICE
    WHERE ORDID = :old.ORDID AND ITEMID = :old.ITEMID;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a query againts the table on which the trigger fired within the trigger itself. In your case, I think that your trigger could be rewritten as a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that simply sets `ITEMTOT`:

```
BEFORE UPDATE OF QTY,ACTUALPRICE ON ITEM
FOR EACH ROW
    :new.ITEMTOT = :new.QTY * :new.ACTUALPRICE
END;
```